# Regular URL parsing does not work correct with @ symbol

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular exception:

```
(?:([^\:]*)\:\/\/)?(?:([^\:\@]*)(?:\:([^\@]*))?\@)?(?:([^\/\:]*)\.(?=[^\.\/\:]*\.[^\.\/\:]*))?([^\.\/\:]*)(?:\.([^\/\.\:]*))?(?:\:([0-9]*))?(\/[^\?#]*(?=.*?\/)\/)?([^\?#]*)?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?
```

1) If parse url: http://test.ru/long/path/file.ext?queryparam=123&more=234 -  its OK

http://viper-7.com/QNCAQu

2) If parse url: ftp://admin:pass@server.com/long/path/file.ext -  its OK

http://viper-7.com/jkQHpP

3) BUT, if in GET parameter exist [AT] (@), it is not work correct!

Example: http://test.ru/long/path/file.ext?queryparam=123&mail=test@domain.com

http://viper-7.com/9qIdcj

PS. Regular exception find on stackoverflow, but don't remember the topic.:(

Comment: What does this regex do?

Comment: You can probably enhance your question if you explain what the task is and how the expression fails to accomplish it. It's possible that the 6 external links explain it but most users won't care checking. Additionally, why are all `@` escaped with backslash?

Comment: It is a universal expression to parse links to segments.

If you use it to parse URL in the GET parameter is the @ character is present - all that comes to this character he considers FTP login, as this expression can also disassemble and FTP URLs.

Comment: @ViktorKulikov you really should not be using a regular expression to do this as it is neither accurate nor efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct that it fails because it's a malformed url.

The url should read

```
http://test.ru/long/path/file.ext?queryparam=123&mail=test%40domain.com
```

instead of the malformed test@domain.com.

the javascript function `encodeURIComponent('@');` is your friend :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to parse a URL, regex is not the way. PHP has a built in function called [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse_url) that will break the URL up into its segments to easily access. More efficient and way less code. In addition you can further break up the query segment with [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) Lastly, if you want to break up the path you can use [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) as well. PHP has all these readily available, you just need to start using them.